# Is it possible to add an array value to a row in a MySql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a CRUD operation with a form and I was wondering if like for example, a student is asked to register for say 4 subjects for an exam and they have to choose from a list, is it possible for those subject to appear in a single row on a column or do I have to create a seperate table for that?

Comment: Read about database normalization. Have fun.

Comment: It is but makes no sense to do it.@fancyPants gave you a good hint.I would advise that you read a book about mysql or watch some tutorials first

Answer (score 1):

It's generally good practice to add a separate table for that so that you can then use the information to, for example, find out which students need to take the economics exam.  If you put comma separated values into a column, it's harder to get that information back.

If you're using newer versions of MySQL (5.7 or later), you could also check out the JSON column type which caters for storing more than just a single value in one column - but I'd still recommend using a separate table in most cases for good data design.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible. You could for instance write a string `'Math,Literature,Arts'`.

However, you should only do this when you are never interested in the separate parts. If you never need a query to ask how many students registered for `'Math'` or whether student 123 registered for `'Arts'` etc., then no problem.

This would be a very rare case, though. Usually you *are*  interested in the separate subjects, so store them separately, i.e. have a `Student` table, a `subject` table, and a `student_subject` table.